# ng build --prod throwing exception

Tags: angular, angular-cli

While creating the build for production getting below error

```
ERROR in common.162374785956ac8f24a6.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (C:\path\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:162:59)
    at module.exports (C:\path\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\worker.js:16:41)
    at handle (C:\path\node_modules\worker-farm\lib\child\index.js:44:8)
    at process. (C:\path\node_modules\worker-farm\lib\child\index.js:51:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:812:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Below Angular-CLI version details:

```
$ ng --version

Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of `terser` are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.16.1 version of terser

Comment: yeah it's a bug, check [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3407#issuecomment-459985313)

Comment: @molamk thank you, buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug reported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13582) for the current latest version of `terser 3.16`, till then you can go with the workaround.

Install compatible terser 3.14 version to resolve this

```
npm i terser@3.14
```

Comment: so I need to downgrade the version from 3.16.1 to 3.14 right?

Comment: Yes, that's the work around as of now

Comment: @AmitChigadani good work. The bug is in `Terser` though, not `Angular`, see [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3407#issuecomment-459985313)

Comment: @molamk Yes, thanks for notifying that